# Use of TypeCatalog

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I thought this would be easy, but after scanning many pages Google hasn't come to my aid.

I have the following in a test method.

```
var tCatalog = new TypeCatalog(typeof (ISystemIndex));
var aCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof (ISystemIndex).Assembly);
```

`tCatalog.Parts` comes up empty, while `aCatalog.Parts.Count` is 3 (one of them comes from a class decorated with `[Export(typeof(ISystemIndex))]`, the other two from classes inheriting from a base w/ Export defined)

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to initialize the `TypeCatalog` in some way?

The problem I'm trying to solve is to create a catalog with a subset of the exportable classes in my assembly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to create a `TypeCatalog` for the interface definition, which is not exported, as there is no `[Export]` attribute decorating the `ISystemIndex` interface.

If you had a class such as

```
[Export(typeof(ISystemIndex))]
public class MySystemIndex : ISystemIndex
{
}
```

and you would create a type catalog

```
var tCatalog = new TypeCatalog(typeof(MySystemIndex));
```

then you would have seen it in `tCatalog.Parts`.

**EDIT**

If you want to have a catalog filtered by a certain criteria (e.g. in your case, exports only), check out MEF's documentation about [Filtering Catalogs](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Filtering%20Catalogs&referringTitle=Parts%20Lifetime)

Comment: What is the point of the `Export` attribute if he directly builds the `TypeCatalog` on `typeof(MySystemIndex)`, not on `typeof(ISystemIndex)`?

Comment: @ProfK The type(s) passed to `TypeCatalog` merely tell the catalog which types should be reflected to look for exports. Without the export attribute the catalog won't contain any parts.